# How Do I Use NSTimer, start/stop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, timer, nstimer

How would I use NSTimer to make an action happen every second?

regards Nikita.

Comment: Please review your previous questions and accept other users' answers. This will encourage us to answer your question.

Comment: developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: thanks Craig, I'll do that from now on,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it this way,

```
-(void)fireTimer{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selected(timeOut:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Now, this will call your timeOut: selector every 1 sec and then in the timeOut:

```
-(void)timeOut:(NSTimer*)timer{
   static int count = 0;
   count++;
   if(count == 60){
     [timer invalidate]; 
     timer = nil;
   }
}
```

There are many apis. I hope you would like to check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html.